# Is there any country where hacking back is legal?

Tags: hacking, ethical-hacking

Building on this unanswered question: [Under what circumstances could laying hacker "traps" cause civil or criminal liability for non-law enforcement civilians?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/56150)

I was wondering if there was any place where hacking back is legal, and if would be possible for companies to base their operations there, so they have a legal basis to hack back at their attackers.

As far as I can tell, it is illegal in most places, but I'd like to make sure there isn't a country that permits it.

Comment: Usually, laws don't permit anything, they forbid something. If I re-state your question as "is there any country that does not have an explicit (criminal) law forbidding 'hacking'?" I think you get the result you want, and the answer might be "Yes, they never got around to it".

Comment: This could also potentially be answered by finding a documented case where someone has done this, and it was either found to be legal in court or declared to be so by a relevant government official.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This report summarizes the state of [cyber-crime law in Africa](https://rm.coe.int/16806b8a79), noting that 60% of African nations have no laws against hacking (much less laws against "hacking back"). It is 5 years old so there may be some changes.